# spriteKit accessing variable from another class?

Tags: sprite-kit

Ok, so for my mainGameScene class i have scoring implemented by declaring and synthesizing two properties:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger score;
@property (nonatomic) SKLabelNode *scorelabel;
```

Creating a label:

```
scorelabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"chalkDuster"];
scorelabel.name = @"scoreCounter";
scorelabel.text = @"0";
scorelabel.fontSize = 30;
scorelabel.position = CGPointMake(50, 25);
[self.scene addChild:scorelabel]
```

And then use an if statement to increase it:

```
if (node.position.x > 320) {
        score++;
        scorelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)score];
    }
```

What i need to know is how i can access scorelabel.text and use it in my gameOverScene Class.
Also, how can i create a variable to keep track of a highscore to also display in gameOverScene.

Answer (score 1):

For keeping track of the high score, you should use user defaults:

```
int highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefualts] objectForKey@"High Score"] integerValue];
```

Where you set the high score to be an NSNumber in the user defaults, you make it an int here.

```
if (highScore){
    if (highScore < score){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"High Score"];
    }
}
else{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"High Score"];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then you can transition to your game over scene, and pull the high score from the User defaults again.

As for passing the label between scenes, you could set the `scorelabel.text` property as another user default, or use the method I described for passing ints with an SKLabelNode instead over here.

[Passing integer between scenes, iphone game sprite-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817840/passing-integer-between-scenes-iphone-game-sprite-kit/21819653#21819653)

Comment: How do i pull from the user defaults?

Comment: For the code you showed me above, where should that be at. And i don't really understand your other method. If i declare my variable in .h of my mainGameClass, why can't i use it in .m of my gameOverClass.

Comment: Because you won't have the instance of your mainGameClass when you are in your gameOverClass

Comment: ok so if i want scoreEnd.text in gameOver.m to equal an NSInteger in mainGame.h, whats the format i need

Comment: Use the code above to set an integer property on gameOver to be the integer from mainGame, and then created the SKLabelNode's text using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.scoreEndInt];`

Comment: Ive gotten showing your score after a certain round to work but for the high score it shows 116 every time i play and i have now idea how its getting there. Can you explain that IF statement to me so i can try to solve this.

Comment: Actually, its seems to be working now. One last question. How can i reset the highscore?

Comment: the if statement checks to make sure the high score exists (AKA is not 0 or nan), and if it does it then checks to see if the high score is lower than the score you just got.  If it is, it updates the high score (which is stored as an NSNumber) otherwise it does nothing.  If the high score does not exist, it sets it to be the score you just got.

Comment: you could either delete the app, or write code for a reset button and have it call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@0 forKey:@"High Score"];`