# Passing integer between scenes, iphone game sprite-kit

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, scene

I have a scene where the user chooses level in a game, then i want to switch to a game scene with the level the user chose. I want to create the game scene with the right level but to do this i need to pass an integer which is the level-number to the game scene so i know which level to load.

My question is, how do i accomplish this? I have looked at the userdata property of nodes but could not figure out how to use it to accomplish what i want. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `[self.view presentScene:scene transition:transition]` inside of your level selection scene, first set up your new scene with the level number. SO:

```
//GameScene.h
//This is the public interface for your game scene
@import SpriteKit;
@interface GameScene : SKScene
@property (nonatomic, assing)NSInteger levelNumber;
@end
```

And then

```
//Level Selection Scen
//Select.m
#import "GameScene.h"
... Rest of your code
User selects level and you prepare for transition and call
- (void)transitionToLevel:(NSInteger)level{
    GameScene *destinationScene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    destinationScene.levelNumber = level;
    SKTransition *transition = //Set up transition here
    [self.view presentScene:destinationScene transition:transition];
}
```

And in your game scene's implementation

```
//GameScene.m
#import "GameScene.h"
@implementation GameScene
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize){
    if (self.levelNumber == 1){
        [self playLevelOne]; //Where this is where you play your game
    }
    else if (self.levelNumber == 2){
        [self playLevelTwo];
    }
}
- (void)playLevelOne{
    //Level Implementation
}
- (void)playLevelTwo{
    //Level Implementation
}
@end
```

You would do this for each level you plan to support

Answer (score 0):

```
    // First Scene
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(12345, forKey:"SCORE")

    // Second Scene
    if let myScore: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SCORE") {
        println(myScore)
        finalScore = myScore as IntegerLiteralType
    }
```